# How do openssl commands sign messages using ed25519

Tags: openssl

I am trying to sign data using Ed25519 algorithm in OpenSSL. I have reinstalled OpenSSL and confirmed that my OpenSSL version supports Ed25519. However, when I try to sign data using the openssl dgst command with the -ed25519 flag, I get an error message saying "Unrecognized flag ed25519". Here is the command I am using:

```
openssl dgst -sign <private_key_file> -ed25519 -out <signature_file> <data_file>
```

I have also tried using the openssl pkeyutl command to sign the data, but I get an error message saying "Error initializing context". Here is the command I am using:

```
openssl pkeyutl -sign -inkey <private_key_file> -keyform PEM -in <data_file> -out <signature_file> -pkeyopt digest:ed25519
```

I have confirmed that my private key is in PEM format and that my OpenSSL version supports Ed25519. What could be causing these errors, and how can I sign data using Ed25519 algorithm in OpenSSL?

Comment: pkeyutl: Error initializing context
139766041200448:error:0608D096:digital envelope routines:EVP_PKEY_sign_init:operation not supported for this keytype:crypto/evp/pmeth_fn.c:40:

Comment: You can't do it from the commandline utility -- which is offtopic anyway. `pkeyutl` only works for algorithms whose hashing step is separable, which EdDSA isn't (though ph-EdDSA would be, if implemented). `dgst` doesn't have _any_ options for algorithms like `-ed25519 -rsa -ecdsa`, it determines the algorithm from the privatekey (or publickey for verify), but it also doesn't work for EdDSA, whose implementation doesn't support streaming. You can write code and that would be ontopic; see man 3 EVP_DigestSign and (more exactly) man 7 EVP_SIGNATURE-ED25519 .

Answer (score 2):

Since v3.0.1 OpenSSL CLI supports signing with Ed25519 (see [here](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/6988)).

Example:

```bash
# generate keys
openssl genpkey -algorithm Ed25519 -out secret.pem
openssl pkey -in secret.pem -pubout -out public.pem

# generate signature
openssl pkeyutl -sign -inkey secret.pem -out signature.bin -rawin -in message.bin

# verify signature
openssl pkeyutl -verify -pubin -inkey public.pem -rawin -in message.bin -sigfile signature.bin
```